# Implementation of sizeof operator

Tags: c, linux, gcc, sizeof, typecast-operator

I have tried implementing the sizeof operator. I have done in this way:

```
#define my_sizeof(x) ((&x + 1) - &x)
```

But it always ended up in giving the result as '1' for either of the data type.

I have then googled it, and I found the following code:

```
#define my_size(x) ((char *)(&x + 1) - (char *)&x)
```

And the code is working if it is **typecasted**, I don't understand why. This code is also PADDING a STRUCTURE perfectly.

It is also working for:

```
#define my_sizeof(x) (unsigned int)(&x + 1) - (unsigned int)(&x)
```

Can anyone please explain how is it working if typecasted?

Comment: Casting to `unsigned int` is a bad idea. `uintptr_t` is better but still involves an annoying but unavoidable implicit conversion.

Comment: You basically *cannot* implement `sizeof`. It is an essential part of the C language

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The result of pointer subtraction is in *elements* and not in bytes. Thus the first expression evaluates to `1` by definition.

This aside, you really ought to use parentheses in macros:

```
#define my_sizeof(x) ((&x + 1) - &x)
#define my_sizeof(x) ((char *)(&x + 1) - (char *)&x)
```

Otherwise attempting to use `my_sizeof()` in an expression can lead to errors.

Comment: The macros are hopeless as a means of replacing `sizeof`. They evaluate the argument (twice too)... Think of `my_sizeof(x++)`.

Answer (score 10):

> ```
> #define my_sizeof(x) ((char *)(&x + 1) - (char *)&x)
> ```

This `my_sizeof()` macro will not work in the following cases:

1. `sizeof 1` - 4 byte (for a platform with 4-byte `int`)
       `my_sizeof(1)` - won't compile at all.
2. `sizeof (int)` - 4 byte(for a platform with 4-byte `int`)
       `my_sizeof(int)` - won't compile code at all.

It will work only for variables. It won't work for data types like `int`, `float`, `char` etc., for literals like `2`, `3.4`, `'A'`, etc., nor for rvalue expressions like `a+b` or `foo()`.

Comment: This would make a great comment, because it doesn't answer the question asked, yet it is ["constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)...

Comment: it will also not correctly report the size at all, because of alignment. in example a 6 byte sized variable will report 8.

Comment: @OlSen If `&x + 1` is 8 bytes past `&x`, then [the `sizeof(x)` is in fact 8](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note106): "For pointer subtraction, the result of the difference between the character pointers is similarly divided by **the size of the object originally pointed to**."

Answer (score 8):

The `sizeof` operator is part of the C (and C++) language specification, and is implemented inside the compiler (the front-end). There is no way to implement it with other C constructs (unless you use GCC extensions like [typeof](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html)) because it can accept either types or expressions as operand, without making any side-effect (e.g. `sizeof((i>1)?i:(1/i))` won't crash when `i==0` but your macro `my_sizeof` would crash with a division by zero). See also [C coding guidelines](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.3.4.html), and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof).

You should understand C [pointer arithmetic](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html). See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117486/c-pointer-arithmetic). Pointer difference is expressed in elements not bytes.

Answer (score 8):

```
#define my_sizeof(x) ((&x + 1) - &x)
```

`&x` gives the address of the variable (lets say double x) declared in the program and incrementing it with 1 gives the address where the next variable of the type x can be stored (here `addr_of(x) + 8`, for the size of a double is 8Byte).

The difference gives the result that how many variables of type of `x` can be stored in that amount of memory which will obviously be 1 for the type x (for incrementing it with 1 and taking the difference is what we've done).

```
#define my_size(x) ((char *)(&x + 1) - (char *)&x)
```

typecasting it into `char*` and taking the difference will tell us how many variables of type `char` can be stored in the given memory space (the difference). Since each `char` requires only 1 Byte of memory therefore (amount of memory)/1 will give the number of bytes between two successive memory locations of the type of variable passed on to the macro and hence the amount of memory that the variable of type `x` requires.

But you won't be able to pass any literal to this macro and know their size.

Answer (score 6):

> But it always ended up in giving the result as '1' for either of the data type

Yes, that's how pointer arithmetic works.  It works in units of the type being pointed to.  So casting to `char *` works units of `char`, which is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This will work for both literals and variables.

```
#define my_sizeof(x) (char*) (&(((__typeof__(x) *)0)[1])) - (char *)(&(((__typeof__(x) *)0)[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#define my_sizeof(x) ((&x + 1) - &x)
```

- This is basically (difference of two memory values) / (size of the data type).
- It gives you the number in which how many number of elements of type x can be stored. And that is 1. You can fit one full x element in this memory space.
- When we typecast it to some other datatype, it represents how many number of elements of that datatype can be stored in this memory space.

```
#define my_size(x) ((char *)(&x + 1) - (char *)&x)
```

- Typecasting it to (char *) gives you the exact number of bytes of memory because char is of one byte.

```
#define my_sizeof(x) (unsigned int)(&x + 1) - (unsigned int)(&x)
```

- It will give you compilation error as you are typecasting a pointer type to int.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to learn about formatting answers using Markdown.

Answer (score 0):

I searched this yesterday, and I found this macro:

```
#define mysizeof(X)  ((X*)0+1)
```

Which expands X only once (no error as double evaluation of expression like x++), and it works fine until now.

Comment: Although this macro had no error with my tests with structures, the use of  <sizeof()> operator covers much more general situations. For example, mysizeof(2) cannot compile, but sizeof(2) yields 4, the integer's size.

Comment: Expected expression.

Answer (score -1):

# define my_sizeof(x) ((&x + 1) - &x)

&x gives the address of your variable and incrementing it with one (&x + 1), will give the address, where another variable of type x could be stored.
Now if we do arithmetic over these addresses like ((&x + 1) - &x), then it will tell that within ((&x + 1) - &x) address range 1 variable of type x could be stored.

Now, if we typecast that amount of memory with (char *) [because size of char is 1 byte and incrementing a char * would move with one byte only], then we would get the number of bytes type x is consuming

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
//#define mySizeOf(T) (char*)(&T + 1) - (char*)(&T)

        template<class T>
size_t mySizeOf(T)
{
        T temp1;
        return (char*)(&temp1 + 1) - (char*)(&temp1);
}
int main()
{
        int num = 5;
        long numl = 10;
        long long numll = 100;
        unsigned int num_un_sz = 500;

        cout<<"size of int="<<mySizeOf(num) << endl;
        cout<<"size of long="<<mySizeOf(numl) << endl;
        cout<<"size of long long ="<<mySizeOf(numll) << endl;
        cout<<"size of unsigned int="<<mySizeOf(num_un_sz) << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `<bits/stdc++.h>`  is *not* a standard header